# Comparison with parsed numbers fails

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compare an array of times with the current local time. But comparing the numbers fails for some values. As far as I could detect, it is not always failing the same time string. Im really out of ideas what the reason could be.

```
function lastPassedTimeIndex() {
  const d = new Date();
  const nowHr = d.getHours();
  const nowMin = d.getMinutes();

  let lastPassedTimeIndex = 0;
  const currentTimes = ['05:20', '06:57', '12:46', '15:48', '18:30', '20:02'];

  for (const time of currentTimes) {
     const t = time.split(':');
     const printHr = parseInt(t[0], 10);
     const printMin = parseInt(t[1], 10);

     if ((printHr < nowHr) && (printMin < nowMin)) {
        console.log(time, 'previous from now');
        lastPassedTimeIndex++;
     }
     else if ((printHr === nowHr) && (printMin < nowMin)) {
        console.log(time, 'previous from now, but hour is correct');
        lastPassedTimeIndex++;
     }
     else if ((printHr === nowHr) && (printMin >= nowMin)) {
        console.log(time, 'is upcoming or now and hour is correct');
        lastPassedTimeIndex++;
     }
     else if ((printHr > nowHr)) {
        console.log(time, 'is upcoming, hour is larger');
     }
     else {
        console.log('I have no idea!');
     }
  }

  console.log('LastPassedTimeIndex ', lastPassedTimeIndex);
  return lastPassedTimeIndex;
}
```

This is my console output:

```
> I have no idea! 
> I have no idea!
> 12:46 is upcoming, hour is larger
> 15:48 is upcoming, hour is larger
> 18:30 is upcoming, hour is larger
> 20:02 is upcoming, hour is larger
> LastPassedTimeIndex  0
```

Comment: i feel like we could be of more help if you told us what time you ran this code

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that. The time was 07:15

Comment: You have a condition `(printHr < nowHr) && (printMin < nowMin)` but there may be times when the hour is less but minute is equal or greater. There is nothing to catch that case. If the hour is less, why even bother checking the minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see one error, fixed this way:

```
 const printHr = parseInt(t[0], 10);
 const printMin = parseInt(t[1], 10);

 if ((printHr < nowHr) /* Take out what was here */) {
    console.log(time, 'previous from now');
    lastPassedTimeIndex++;
 }
```

Comment: You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Just saying "do this" is not that helpful.

Comment: Thanks, there was really an issue there. But there was also webpack not updating properly my code -.-

Answer (score 0):

The minutes have to be compared only when the hours are the same, or just compare as strings:

```js
var time = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0, 5)
var times = ['05:20', '06:57', '12:46', '15:48', '18:30', '20:02']

console.log( time, times.findIndex(t => t >= time) - 1 )
```